# How can dictionary items be used as function kwargs in parent and child/sub functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I am writing a code in which some functions require many input variables. So, I thought it would be a good idea to make these input variables callable kwargs via a dictionary. I'm having trouble with functions kwargs called by parent functions. As a simple example, consider the code below.

```
import numpy as np

## generate some data and call function via dict

def f(x):
    return np.cos(x)

data_one = np.linspace(1, 10, 10) # x
data_two = f(data_one) # y

xy_dict = dict(x=data_one, y=data_two) ## put x,y into dict

def try_dict_ops(x, y):
    c = [x[i] - y[i] for i in range(len(x)) if len(x) == len(y)]
    return np.array(c)

print(try_dict_ops(**xy_dict)) 
## prints array, it works
```

Now I'll introduce a parent function and corresponding data dict.

```
abxy_dict = dict(a=1, b=4, x=data_one, y=data_two)

def try_nested_dict_ops(a, b, x, y):
    g = [try_dict_ops(x, y)[i] * a + b for i in range(len(x))]
    return np.array(g)

print(try_nested_dict_ops(**abxy_dict))
## prints array, it works
```

My question is regarding the different methods of calling the parent function, which in turns calls on the sub-function defined above. Is there a simpler way to do this without explicitly putting `x` and `y` in `abxy_dict`? Moreover, what if a parent function calls two different subfunctions, both of which share kwargs names but not necessarily args values - is my goal still possible given such a setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a dictionary to pass in keyword arguments is just a different spelling of calling a function. It doesn't matter *to the function itself* how it was called, it'll get those arguments one way or another.

In other words, the function *doesn't care* if you used

```
xy_dict = dict(x=data_one, y=data_two)
try_dict_ops(**xy_dict)
```

or

```
try_dict_ops(x=data_one, y=data_two)
```

or

```
try_dict_ops(data_one, data_two)
```

If your function doesn't actually need access to `x` and `y` (so the sole purpose of passing them in is to pass them on to the transitive function calls) then just capture those arguments in a `**kwargs` catch-all:

```
def try_nested_dict_ops(a, b, **kwargs):
    g = [try_dict_ops(**kwargs)[i] * a + b for i in range(len(x))]
    return np.array(g)
```

Now all extra *keyword* arguments passed to `try_nested_dict_ops()` are passed on to the `try_dict_ops()` call, without the function itself needing to know what those arguments are. You can use this for multiple function calls.

You do then require that `x` and `y` are passed in as keyword arguments, not as positional arguments.

Comment: Extremely useful, thank you! As a quick aside, is it possible for a function to have callable kwargs from multiple dictionaries?

Comment: @mikey again, don't confuse the similar syntax used for calling and for defining function parameters. As of Python 3.5 you can specify multiple dictionaries with `**name` in a call. All key-values combined are passed to the function. It is up to the function if it has explicitly named parameters and / or a catch-all parameter.